# Как в названии столбца JTable поставить JCheckBox?

Tags: java, swing

В первом столбце у меня отображается CheckBox при клике на который выделяется вся строка. Но как мне сделать, чтобы в названии тоже был CheckBox при клике на который у меня бы автоматически заполнялись все остальные CheckBox. В данной картинке на месте нужного мне CheckBox стоит java.swing.Default ....
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
package SimpleTables;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class JtableWithCheckbox extends JFrame {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JtableWithCheckbox form = new JtableWithCheckbox();
                form.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
    public JtableWithCheckbox(){
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(200,200,800,300);
        setTitle("ProgrammingWizards");
        getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane();
        scroll.setBounds(70,80,600,200);
        getContentPane().add(scroll);

        final JTable table = new JTable();
        scroll.setViewportView(table);

        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(){
            public Class<?> getColumnClass(int column){
                switch(column){
                    case 0: return Boolean.class;
                    case 1: return String.class;
                    case 2: return String.class;
                    case 3: return String.class;
                    case 4: return String.class;
                    default: return String.class;
                }
            }
        };
        JCheckBox check = new JCheckBox();
        table.setModel(model);
        JLabel lab = new JLabel("Hello");
        DefaultCellEditor editor =
                new DefaultCellEditor(check);
        model.addColumn(editor);
        model.addColumn("Position");
        model.addColumn("Element");
        model.addColumn("Construction");
        model.addColumn("TCE");
        for (int i = 0; i<=7;i++){
            model.addRow(new Object[0]);
            model.setValueAt(false,i,0);
            model.setValueAt("Row" + (i+1), i,1);
            model.setValueAt("Column 2", i, 2);
            model.setValueAt("Column 3", i , 3);
            model.setValueAt("Column 4", i , 4);
        }
        JButton btn = new JButton("Get Selected");
        btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                for (int i = 0;i<table.getRowCount(); i++){
                    Boolean checked = Boolean.valueOf((table.getValueAt(i,0)).toString());
                    String col = table.getValueAt(i,1).toString();
                    if(checked){
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,col);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        btn.setBounds(20,30,139,30);
        getContentPane().add(btn);

    }
}
```

Comment: Может рядом левее от названия поставить чекбокс?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29963916/4711135

Comment: Да левее от названия могу поставить